# Adding a window listener to a WPF-Window?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

How can I add an window/event listener/handler to a wpf-window? I want to know, if the user wants to close the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override OnClosing inside the Window.xaml.cs.

Comment: Where can i find the Window.xaml.cs-file?

Comment: The actual name depends on the name of the XAML file (they are both generated when adding a WPF Window). It will be [Windowname].xaml.cs

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the Closing event of your Window. You can cancel the action using the EventArgs (and its Cancel property)